# Saving data to different tables from a single form in Dynamics AX

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

How can we allow a Dynamics AX form to allow saving data on the grid to two independent tables:
[image]

[image]

When I click on +New it always adds the row to the first grid. We are looking for a way to add row independently for each grid on this form.

Comment: Is it about saving data to different tables or about creating rows in both grids simultaneoursly using the `New` button? Creating and saving records are two different actions, can you clarify what you are trying to achieve step by step?

Answer (score 1):

Your `+New` button is most likely a `command button` and has a single associated DataSource or inherited DataSource. So when you click `+New`, it can only do the single one.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/action-pane-button-overview

So you need to write some code or add a second `Command Button` with a different DataSource if you want the button to do two new records at the same time.